# US companies in Cuba during Batista's rule

Tags: united-states, international-relations, cuba

Reading the history, it states that under Castro, they nationalized many if not all US companies. My question is: does anyone know what companies these were? As in what oil companies were there at the time? Following this, if there is any data on wages paid by the companies? I'm writing a paper and I'm trying to show unfair treatment, and I am not having luck on specifics.

A quick search found this:

http://www.democraticunderground.com/discuss/duboard.php?az=view_all&address=389x4653650

Comment: I can't answer this question, but for the paper it's worth looking into the level of organised crime and the country of origin for those criminals - I remember hearing that the level of prostituion caused by being a playground for wealthy foreigners was a big factor - but I have no idea if that is true, and it is clearly a loaded proposition.

Comment: Answer: A bunch of casinos. Source: *"The Godfather"* :)

Comment: lol best answer yet! Im over it. no worries. thanks though.

Comment: I'm tempted to suggest migrating this to History.SE

Comment: You are probably right. It is for a politics class that why I put it here

Answer (score 1):

After the revolution, RAND released a report [on U.S. interests in Cuba](https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/papers/2008/P2923.pdf) that were nationalized. It doesn't have a list of companies, but it has a breakdown of the values in each industry.

Answer (score 0):

Acording to [this reference](https://en.granma.cu/cuba/2015-08-10/cuba-nationalizes-us-companies) 26 US companies or companies dominated by US owners were nationalized. Among them such oil companies like Texaco, Esso and Sinclair. So here the complete list of companies from that reference:

1. Compañía Cubana de Electricidad.
2. Compañía Cubana de Teléfonos.
3. Esso Standard Oil, S.A. División de Cu­ba.
4. Texas Company West Indian.
5. Sinclair Cuba Oil Company, S.A.
6. Central Cunagua, S.A.
7. Compañía Azucarera Atlántica del Gol­fo, S.A.

8.- Compañía Central Altagracia, S.A.

9. Miranda Sugar States.
10. Compañía Cubana, S.A.
11. The Cuban American Sugar MilI.
12. Cuban Trading Company.
13. The New Tuinicú Sugar Com­pa­ny.
14. The Francisco Sugar Company.
15. Compañía Azucarera Céspedes.
16. Manatí Sugar Company.
17. Punta Alegre Sugar Sales Com­pa­ny.
18. Baraguá Industrial Corporation of New York.
19. Florida Industrial Corporation of New York.
20. Macareño Industrial Corporation of New York.
21. General Sugar States.

22.- Compañía Azucarera Vertientes Ca­magüey de Cuba.

23. Guantánamo Sugar Company.
24. United Fruit Company.
25. Compañía Azucarera Soledad S.A.
26. Central Ermita, S.A.

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you would take the list of companies from the link and include them in the answer.

Comment: @Joe W OK, but not shure if all of them are US ones.

Comment: According to your answer they are all US companies. Either they are and they should be listed in the answer or they are not and your answer is wrong.

Comment: @Joe W Acording to cuban oficials they defenetly are or were.

Comment: My point was you stated they where in your answer and then you questioned if they where in a comment. Either they are and the answer is good or they are not and you should not have posted an answer.